# Error: no match for call to '(Household)

Tags: c++

So basically I have an error that to me makes no sense. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work, so I figured that you guys would be able to help me. This is my first post on this website by the way.

I am working on a  program that involves a class called "household.cc, h" and a test program.

this is Household.h (the code in question)

```
class Household{
public:


    // Default constructor
    Household(std::string nme, std::string adrs, int peeps, int ncome);
    Household();

    Household(std::string& nme, std::string& adrs, int& peeps, int& ncome);
```

This is my Household.cc file in question

```
// constructors

Household::Household(std::string nme, std::string adrs, int peeps, int ncome){
    name = nme;
    address = adrs;
    numpeople = peeps;
    income = ncome;
    }

Household::Household(std::string& nme, std::string& adrs, int& peeps, int& ncome){
    name =nme;
    address = adrs;
    numpeople=peeps;
    income=ncome;
}


Household::Household(){
    name = "";
    address = "";
    numpeople = 0;
    income =0;
}
```

and the test class code in question is:

```
Household temp; 
string n; 
int i; 

cout<< "Please enter the name, press enter, then the income of the house\n";
            getline(cin, n);
            cin >>  i;
            myWard.removeHouse(temp(n, n, i, i));
            break;
```

the error message is

```
Error: no match for call to '(Household) (std:string&, std::string&, int&, int&)'
```

I really don't understand why this is happening because my Household constructor does have all of these parameters. I may be missing something obvious but its not so obvious to me. This is the first time I have ever worked with c++ also.

edit: removeHouse and myWard are irrelevant in this question, but I added the temp code. The problem is the code

```
temp(n,n,i,i)
```

thats where the error is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what is myward? Provide full code please

Comment: What is `removeHouse`?

Comment: You have an ambiguous overload of the 4-parameter constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized with a **default constructor** the **temp** object, then **later** you tried to re-initialize it with **another constructor**.. that's the problem.

```
Household temp;  <-- initialized with DEFAULT constructor
string n; 
int i; 

cout<< "Please enter the name, press enter, then the income of the house\n";
            getline(cin, n);
            cin >>  i;
            myWard.removeHouse(temp(n, n, i, i)); <-- RE-initialize?? Bad idea..
            break;
```

Do initialize the object with the constructor you want (the 4-arguments one I suppose) and then use the object.

Also: gcc is probably being used and it warns you that with that set of arguments, no resolution is available.

Something like this might work:

```
string n; 
int i; 

// do initialize n and i to something meaningful here

Household temp(n, n, i, i);

cout<< "Please enter the name, press enter, then the income of the house\n";
            getline(cin, n);
            cin >>  i;
            myWard.removeHouse(temp);
            break;
```

I know nothing of the other functions and regarding the program's behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `temp(n, n, i, i)` does not "re-call" the constructor, which is what you appear to be trying to do. Rather, that expression attempts to call the function-application operator, `operator()`, on the `temp` object. You haven't provided such an operator for your class, so the compiler rightly complains.

You cannot re-call an object's constructor. What you *can* do, though, is wait to declare the object until you really need it, and then call the constructor there:

```
{
  cout<< "Please enter the name, press enter, then the income of the house\n";
  getline(cin, n);
  cin >>  i;
  Household temp(n, n, i, i);
  myWard.removeHouse(temp);
}
break;
```

I've added braces because this code looks like it's part of a `switch` statement. Declaring variables in the middle of a `switch` block, as this code would now do with `temp`, can lead to problems; the braces limit the scope of the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be because you have two constructors that only differ by the fact that it takes references.

The compiler feels that it's ambiguous and doesn't know which constructor to call; hence "no match".